# The usage of そんな感じに to end a scene in narration

Tags: meaning, phrases

For example

> そんな感じに日は過ぎて行きました

which may appear at the end of the scene.

Do we have anything similar to this in English?

What is the purpose of using a construction like this instead of naturally letting the scene end (i.e. what meaning/etc. does it add)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm pretty sure there are similar constructions in English... For example:

> And on that note, let's call it a day.

could easily be the end of a scene.

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly for emphasis/embellishment on the day ending. Of course it's not absolutely necessary, but it gives the viewer a sense of conclusion for that part of the story and a transition to another part.